# dropping servers in a load balanced environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I have two signalr asp.net servers running behind a load balancer using Redis.

When my users connect and login, I store an association between the user and their connection id in Redis.  When my users logout/disconnect, I remove the association.

When I take one of my two servers offline, my clients reconnect to the other server. This causes another association to be made, but there is no disconnect event being fired to clean up the left over associations from the downed server.

This is important because it means I can no longer tell if a client is online or not.

How should I be coding to be able to deal with downed servers?

Answer (score 0):

Do you get a "OnReconnected" call when the clients reconnect to the server that is still alive? When clients reconnect to the other server, you should take the required to fix the associations.

You cannot expect to get notifications from a downed server, the reasons why it is down could be many.

Comment: Yes, but there is also the possibility that for whatever reason those clients do not reconnect. So this kind of logic doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I went with (which I'm sure could be improved)

When a client connects, the server writes to Redis the connection id into a list keyed by the server hostname.

Every server runs a task every 30 seconds that writes to Redis with it's hostname and the current time.

Every server also runs a task every 30 seconds that checks for servers that have not updated their timestamp in X amount of time.

When a server is found to no longer be "heartbeating", it pulls the connection ids for downed server and runs the cleanup.